# Is this method to make data approximatly stationary valid?

Tags: time-series, arima, stationarity

I thought up this method to make data stationary for time series modeling with Arima. Does this method make any sense or is it completely flawed?

For stationary data we need a constant mean and variance.

**Step 1:** Partition the data into *n* sets, and calculate the mean and variance on each the *n* partitions. New mean and variance equals the mean and variance of the first partition.

**Step 2:** Transform the mean of each partition by subtracting or adding a constant to the set of points so that the new mean will equal the mean of partition 1.

**Step 3:** Find a scaling factor by setting the variance of the first partition equal to the variance of the second partition. Next, multiply each data point in the second partition by that scaling factor. This should set the variance of partition two to equal partition one.

**Step 4:** Fit Arima to this transformed data, forecast one time step, and perform the inverse operation of the last partition onto the forecasted value.

If I do this transform on every partition, the mean and variance will all be the same as the first partition. If the time step is small, the transform should be approximatly valid for the new predicted value.

Would this approximation be valid/converge to the true solution as data points and partitions increase, and the time step decreases?

If you think it's valid, why? Why Wouldn't the transform mess up the Arima fit? If not valid, why not? Why does this transform mess up the Arima fit? By how much will this transformation mess up the fit?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to assess your method is to actually employ it to a series that has actually been identified as having a changing error variance. I suggest that you write a script to test out your suggested procedure and in this way you can answer your own question as to the validity of your suggestion for an example time series. As stated your question is unanswerable by me without actually following your steps.

Here is a monthly series (100 values) that was simulated and then analyzed (without any knowledge of how it had been created )to extract a useful equation.

106.42180000
106.52310000
107.16100000
107.54770000
108.58580000
109.06040000
108.39190000
109.03420000
108.62970000
109.17610000
109.26100000
109.74330000
109.91110000
110.36590000
111.09530000
111.67710000
112.61290000
112.78900000
112.53360000
112.69260000
112.05640000
112.80140000
113.56820000
114.03360000
113.92130000
114.52090000
115.07210000
115.58770000
116.49890000
116.22230000
116.28600000
115.96300000
115.38920000
115.88420000
116.45560000
116.39630000
116.34920000
117.14230000
117.83130000
117.47930000
118.29500000
118.95320000
119.16990000
118.56290000
118.31370000
118.53630000
118.63620000
119.05070000
118.40140000
119.80770000
120.62600000
120.52950000
120.69500000
121.01230000
121.55450000
121.79610000
121.58630000
122.71950000
123.24040000
122.59030000
118.79360000
119.09070000
118.06250000
118.59590000
119.74000000
116.67910000
117.91960000
117.74500000
120.00620000
123.05880000
123.45650000
120.86730000
120.38030000
121.27480000
122.91580000
123.49020000
124.80820000
122.34040000
123.16010000
117.72260000
114.77890000
119.70050000
113.90680000
113.08350000
113.36290000
114.74080000
120.17530000
122.50790000
124.68600000
123.03420000
126.68660000
124.53100000
123.18900000
125.37530000
121.16230000
118.61020000
123.20670000
120.97600000
124.86020000
123.50470000

[image] with [image]equation here incorporating a error variance change at or about period 49 [image]

The variance change was detected using TSAY's procedure [image] . The residual plot is here [image] with accompanying acf suggesting sufficiency [image] while the acf of the original series is here [image] . Finally the Actual , Fit and Forecast is here [image]

Please post your results from your suggested approach and compare them with what is presented here. Additionally in another question you might actually simulate your own time series , present it and your results in order to substantiate your approach .

I have added a snapshot of the augmented data matrix (periods 65-100) to depict/illustrate the form of the 5 deterministic series that were identified [image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will try it on your data, give me 1-2 days to get it done. 
Your post says generalized linear model, but the equation of the model looks like a differenced Arima(5,1,?). What was the model you used to fit the data? If GLM, what type of exponential distribution did you use, and why did you choose it? 

Also, do you know any documentation I can read on the variance adjusted residual weight procedure mentioned above?

Comment: the model in pdq notation (0,1,0)(1,0,0)12 is a regularly  differenced model with a seasonal autoregessive coefficient AND 5 suporting deterministic input series (3 pulses and two seasonal pulses ) with a deterministic positive variance at period 48. It is a Weighted Least Square Model thus a GLS model . http://docplayer.net/12080848-Outliers-level-shifts-and-variance-changes-in-time-series.html contains the variance change detection material.

Comment: I realized now that what I have proposed is nothing more than stabilizing the variance with a log transform, subtracting a best fit line, and fitting Arima to the errors. 

I thought it would be easier to do this in a partition form, after studying more I realized there is no point. 

Thanks for your help again!