# Weighted least squares versus ordinary

Tags: regression, weighted-regression

Is it ever better to use ordinary least squares *(OLS)* over weighted least squares *(WLS)*? If a model is fit well by *OLS*, will I get worse results if I use *WLS* instead?

Obviously, *OLS* is faster, but who cares if it takes an extra 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

If the variance of the errors from a sarmax model evident a determinstic change at one or more points, this can't be easily ignored and needs to be rectified thus Weighted Least Squares a particular form of GLS is in order..as was discussed in [Is this method to make data approximatly stationary valid?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/412884/is-this-method-to-make-data-approximatly-stationary-valid/413528#413528)

Worst in what sense ?  hypothesis testing ? prediction limits ? mape computation for a specific # of withheld values ? It would all depend !

Comment: I'm looking for an example of where the MAPE of OLS < MAPE of WLS.

Comment: based upon the fitted values or some out-of-sample values ?

Comment: out of sample values

Comment: out of sample mape doesn't change because the modelparametrs don;t change because the values that are under-varianced so to speak simply get adjusted proportionally . The signal remains the same ... what does change is the test of significance for each parameters a a result of normalizaton suggested by TSAY

Comment: So, are you saying weighted least squares never performs worse than ordinary least squares, when it comes to mape of out of sample data? 

Would least squares fit data better than weighted least squares in any metric that you know of? 

Because, I think this would mean I should fit weighted least squares over ordinary least squares in every case (When not concerned about speed).

Comment: It appears to me to never perform worse BUT I believe there is a point of diminishing returns when break points error variance are implemented in the recent history i.e. within the ar memory region that should be studiously avoided..